# Implementar correctamente Angular ui-bootstrap date picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

Acabo de integrar el `datepicker` en un proyecto pero no funciona correctamente.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Date</label>
                <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
         datepicker-popup="mediumDate" 
         is-open="shipment.valuationDatePickerIsOpen" 
        ng-click="shipment.valuationDatePickerOpen()" 
        ng-model="shipment.valuationDate" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
        ng-click="shipment.valuationDatePickerOpen($event)">
         <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
     </button>
</span>
</p>

</div>
```

**Controlador**

```
var vm = this;
    // $scope.Eship;

      vm.valuationDate = new Date();
  vm.valuationDatePickerIsOpen = false;
  vm.opens = [];

  $scope.$watch(function () {
       return vm.valuationDatePickerIsOpen;
   },function(value){
      vm.opens.push("valuationDatePickerIsOpen: " + value + " at: " + new Date());
   });

  vm.valuationDatePickerOpen = function ($event) {

      if ($event) {
          $event.preventDefault();
          $event.stopPropagation(); 
      }
      this.valuationDatePickerIsOpen = true;
  };
```

Se muestra la fecha actual en cuanto carga la vista pero no pasa nada al hacer `click` en el `input` o en el botón.

Comment: no se supone que al input tambien tienes que agregarle la clase datepicker???

Answer (score 1):

Añádele un formato de fecha con la propiedad `datetime-picker` al input

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Date</label>
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
       datetime-picker="dd/MM/yyyy"
       datepicker-popup="mediumDate" 
       is-open="shipment.valuationDatePickerIsOpen" 
       ng-click="shipment.valuationDatePickerOpen()" 
       ng-model="shipment.valuationDate" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
            ng-click="shipment.valuationDatePickerOpen($event);">
             <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
         </button>
    </span>
</p>
```